# Extract next semantic-release version using Regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have some logs outputted by semantic-release. I would like to get the next semantic version.

Here's some of the logs

```
[6:53:27 p.m.] [semantic-release] › ℹ  The next release version is 1.1.1
[6:53:27 p.m.] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "generateNotes" of plugin "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[6:53:27 p.m.] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "generateNotes" of plugin "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[6:53:27 p.m.] [semantic-release] › ⚠  Skip step "prepare" of plugin "@semantic-release/changelog" in dry-run mode
[6:53:27 p.m.] [semantic-release] › ⚠  Skip 1.1.1 tag creation in dry-run mode
[6:53:27 p.m.] [semantic-release] › ✔  Published release 1.1.1 on apk-add-version channel
[6:53:27 p.m.] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Release note for version 1.1.1:
```

I would like to get the `1.1.1` from the logs

I tried:
`yarn semantic-release -d | grep 'Release note' | grep -Eo "(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)"`

which works on local machine, but I want to try a different approach (because `egrep -o` or `greo -Eo` doesn't seem to work in github-actions. It always returns error code 0)

What I'm looking for is
`Release note for version 1.1.1:`

capture `1.1.1` IF `Release not for version` is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `grep -E` is working with [extended regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) which doesn't support `\d`. So you have two solutions:

- use `grep -P` to use Perl regular expression and work with `\d`
- use `grep -E` but change your regex as `[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+` or `[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`